# Is it possible to find $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}} dx$ by parametrizing the curve $y^4-x^4=1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, alternative-proof

I found this integral in a handbook of integrals: $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}} dx$$

I already have evaluated this integral by trigonometric substitutions and my answer agrees with that of the book. Interestingly, the integral is expressible by using the natural logarithm and arc tangent functions. This motivated the idea that maybe $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}
$$

can be parametrized and turns into a rational function. Just like what we do with sine and cosine functions when we use Euler/Wierstrauss substitutions.

So, is it possible to find $f(t)$, $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ in the field of rational functions such that $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$ and $dx=h(t)dt$?

Comment: This is not algebraic geometry.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: Don't they discuss parametrization of polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ in algebraic geometry?

Comment: Isn't the projective curve $Y^4-X^4=Z^4$ non-singular in $\Bbb{P}^2$ (= the homogenized version of your equation)? As one of degree $4$ it has genus $g=3$. If a parametrization by rational function existed, the function field would have genus $g=0$. Thus a parametrization by rational functions cannot exist.

Comment: @Sanath: I think this can be answered with concepts from algebraic geometry. BTW, how is your blog post coming?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I must apologize for saying that this was not algebraic geometry (I saw your above comment). About my blog post: it's coming on well; I'm planning to write an expository paper on higher categories and topoi, beginning from $1 $-category theory. Perhaps I can post one or two sections at a time as a blog post.

Comment: @Sanath: Glad to hear about it! It may be a good idea to post it in smaller bits. Ask mixedmath or anorton for their opinion. They are largely in charge of the blog. For example, you could post a draft there, and/or discuss the details in the [blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14206/the-blog-room).

Comment: @math.noob: The reason is similar to the reason why we can't have a rational parametrization for points on an elliptic curve (those have genus ($g=1\neq0$).

Comment: The difference between solving the integral thrugh a parametrization of the $y^4=1+x^4$ curve, or the substitution $x=\sqrt{\sinh \theta}$, is very close to zero.